# Fancybox not working on CakePHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, fancybox

I am trying to make a gallery, which has multiple thumbs that should popup the original image when  someone clicks on them, like in the first example in the instructions page on fancybox2 page.

After multiple failed attempts, some of which where even the thumbs were not showing up. I have been suggested to use the [CakePHP-Fancybox](https://github.com/destinydriven/CakePHP-Fancybox-Plugin/tree/master/Fancybox) to fix  this, which solved half problem. When someone clicks on the thumbs, that user is being redirected to another page that show the original image, instead of making it float on the gallery itself.

Now I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'` in the `$(".fancybox3").fancybox({`. How can this issue be fixed?

**Controller**:

```
    public function ShowImages(){
        $this->layout = 'default';
        $this->loadModel('GalleryImage');
        $gallery_images = $this->GalleryImage->find('all');
        $this->set('gallery_images', $gallery_images);

    //$image_display = $gallery_image['path']
    }
```

**View**:

```
    <h2>Galeria</h2>
<br>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <?php
        $i=0;
        foreach( $gallery_images as $gallery_image ):?>
    <td align="center" class="thumbnail" style="display:inline-block;">
    <?php
        $src3 =$this->webroot. 'img/gallery/' .$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'];
        //$src3 = 'img/gallery/' .$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'];
        $this->Fancybox->setProperties( array( 
            'class' => 'fancybox3',
            'className' => 'fancybox.image',
            'title'=>'Single Image',
            'rel' => 'gallery1'
            )
        );
        $this->Fancybox->setPreviewContent($this->Timthumb->image('/img/gallery/' . $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'] , array('width' => 267, 'height' => 189)));

        $this->Fancybox->setMainContent($src3);
        echo $this->Fancybox->output();
    ?>
    </td>
    <?php $i++;
        if($i==4){
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            $i=0;   
        }
    ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tr>

</table>
```

**Layout** (head):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> 
<html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title><?php echo $title_for_layout;//titulo dinamico da página?></title>
    <?php
    echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
    //echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
    echo $this->fetch('meta');
    //echo $this->fetch('css');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.11.0.min');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5');        
    echo $this->Html->script('main');
    echo $this->Html->css('main');

    echo $this->Html->script('modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min');

    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap-theme.min');
    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min');
    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap');

    echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min');
    echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap');
    echo $this->Html->script('dropdown');
    echo $this->Html->script('collapse');


    ?>

    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(){
                $(this).dropdown('toggle');
            });
        });    
    </script>
    <!-- src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"-->

    </head>
<body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

        <?php 
                $home_link_image= $this->webroot."img/PushUp.png";
            if(!$this->Session->check('Admin')){
                $home_link = "/html/PushUp_app/";
            }
            else{

                $home_link = "/html/PushUp_app/admins/admin_index";
            }

            echo "<a class=\"pushup_logo\" href=\"".$home_link."\">";
            //echo" <img src=\"".$home_link_image."\" name=\"logo\" id=\"logo\"/>";
        ?>

    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
            <?php 

            //if(!$this->Session->check('User')){
                echo $this->Html->link('Home', array('controller'=>'home', 'action'=>'index'));
            //}
            /*else{

                echo $this->Html->link('Administrador', array('controller'=>'admins','action' =>'admin_index'));
            }*/
            ?>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Serviços <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Música', array('controller'=>'services', 'action'=>'Musica'))?></li>
                <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Animação Temática', array('controller'=>'services', 'action'=>'AnimacaoTematica'))?></li>
                <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Promoção', array('controller'=>'services', 'action'=>'Promocao'))?></li>
                <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Staff', array('controller'=>'services', 'action'=>'Staff'))?></li>
                <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Aluguer', array('controller'=>'services', 'action'=>'Aluguer'))?></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Galeria<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Fotografias', array('controller'=>'galleries', 'action'=>'ShowImages'))?></li> 
                 <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Videos', array('controller'=>'galleries', 'action'=>'ShowVideos'))?></li>              
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Cartaz', array('controller'=>'showbills', 'action'=>'ShowShowbill'))?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Contactos', array('controller'=>'contacts', 'action'=>'ShowContactUs'))?></li>
        <li><?php 
           /* if(!$this->Session->check('User')){
                echo $this->Html->link('Log-in', array('controller'=>'users','action' =>'login'));
            }
            else{

                echo $this->Html->link('Log-out', array('controller'=>'users','action' =>'logout'));
            }*/
            ?>
           </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!--<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
      </form>-->
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">


  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
                    <?php echo $this->Session->flash();?>
  <!-- Example row of columns --><?php echo $this->fetch('content');?><!--carrega o conteudo para a página-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">

    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <footer>
    <p>&copy; Company 2013</p>
  </footer>
</div> <!-- /container -->        
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<!--<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script src="js/main.js"></script>-->

<script>
        var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
        (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
        g.src='//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
    </script>

            <script type="text/javascript" >
                $(document).ready(function() {

                 $(".fancybox3").fancybox({
                        openEffect : 'none',
                        closeEffect : 'none',
                        helpers : {
                            title : {
                                type : 'image'
                            }
                        }
                    });

                });
    </script> 
    <?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to me that your script is not included on that page at all. Did you include fancybox js?

Comment: I did, like this:

         <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />


I copied the includes from the fancybox site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow CakePHP-Convention you will put your Fancybox-Mediacontent into your "App/webroot/img/fancybox-media/" - Directory. If so, you're able to access the Media like:

http://www.my-app.com/img/fancybox-media/

The nice way building casual DOM-Elements in your View is using Cake's Form-Helper:

In your *AppController*:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $helpers = array('Form', 'Session', 'Html');

    // Rest of your Code here

}
```

After that you'll be possible to replace the following line with the one below in your *View*:

**Replace:**

```
echo "<a href=\"gallery/" . $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'] . "\"class=\"fancybox_img\">";
                          echo  $this->Html->image('gallery/' . $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'] . '', array('width' => '189px', 'height' => '267px', 'alt' => $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'] ));
                          echo "</a>";
```

**With:**

```
$this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image('gallery/' . $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'], array('width' => '189px', 'height' => '267px', 'alt' => $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'] )
);
```

And please be sure that your $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'] - Variable stores the name of the Image-File. Also ensure the existance of the Image (Case-Sensitive) in "*App/webroot/gallery/myImage.jpeg*"

Additionally post eventual thrown JS-Errors in your Browsers Dev-Console if you have one. (Try F12)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
My fancybox content is located in C:\wamp\www\html\PushUp_app\app\webroot\fancyBox, i am gonna put it on the webroot/img to try it out. I also have the helpers included, but when i use the Html-> link with Html-image it shows a text link, thats why I am trying to work it out this way, because the image is shown. The $gallery_image variable is working the way it should, the image name is there. I am completelly out of ideas on how to fix this, I have been trying to fix it for almost a week.

Comment: Also it keeps giving me and error that tells me to make a method at the controller called gallery. Is cake assuming that the 'gallery/' is an action?

Comment: Before struggling around try this one: https://github.com/destinydriven/CakePHP-Fancybox-Plugin

Comment: Thanks! This helps, but i get multiple notice(8) APP\Plugin\Fancybox\View\Helper\FancyboxHelper.php, line 123], related to rel, href and title variables, also when I click on my image it opens another page but it is blank, but if I place the url from the example on the 'how to use' guide from the link you posted, it shows that image.
Shouldn't it be floating on the page instead of redirecting?